# inconsistent hoverIntent behavior in chrome, works fine in FF and on other page elements

Tags: jquery, wordpress, firefox, google-chrome, hoverintent

I'm working on a simple hoverIntent bit on two page elements (hovering over "search_over" makes "search" visible, and hovering over "subscribe_over" makes "subscribe" visible), and I can't figure out why it's working on "subscribe_over" and not "search_over". I'm testing now in Chrome and FF, and it works fine on both divs in FF and only on "subscribe_over" in chrome. can you help me figure out why? Maybe also relevant: I was working on this as a stand-alone page, and I'm now in the process of wordpress-ifying it. It might be a product of clashing with functions in wp_head, though I'm not knowledgeable enough about what goes on under the hood there to make an educated guess at the moment.

here's the jquery code:

```
var mouseOver = false; 
var mouseOver_search = false;

    $('#subscribe').hide();
    $('#subscribe').hover(
        function(){ mouseOver = true; },
        function(){ 
            mouseOver = false;
            $(this).fadeOut(300); 
        }
    );  
    $("#subscribe_over").hoverIntent({
        over: appear, // Function to call when mouseover is called    
        timeout: 500, // How often in milliseconds the onmouseout should be checked
        out: disappear // Function to call when mouseout is called    
    });

    function appear() {
        $('#search').hide();
        $("#subscribe").fadeIn(50);
    }

    function disappear() {
        if (mouseOver == false) $("#subscribe").fadeOut(300);
    }

    $('#search').hide();
    $('#search').hover(
        function(){ mouseOver_search = true; },
        function(){ 
            mouseOver_search = false;
            $(this).fadeOut(300); 
        }
    );  
    $("#search_over").hoverIntent({
        over: appear_s, // Function to call when mouseover is called    
        timeout: 500, // How often in milliseconds the onmouseout should be checked
        out: disappear_s // Function to call when mouseout is called    
    });

    function appear_s() {
        $('#subscribe').hide();
        $("#search").fadeIn(50);
    }

    function disappear_s() {
        if (mouseOver_search == false) $("#search").fadeOut(300);
    }
```

so, it's literally the same code copied and pasted for the two separate elements with separate function names. it's twice as long as it needs to be, but it's clear that the two elements are governed identically. if it helps, it's at http://yummrs.com/blog (and is *very* much still under construction!).

last time i had a question answered here, i had the trailing comma of death and it was a simple fix, but i don't see any lingering commas here... thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I had to "lol" pretty hard seeing the 'comma of death' picture :p

Comment: haha... word. i won't be forgetting that one any time soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have defined:

```
<li id="subscribe_over"><a href="#">subscribe &darr;</a></li> 
<li id="search_over"><a>search</a></li>
```

Aren't you missing a `href` for your search `<a>` tag?

Comment: I just validated your HTML in FireFox and it had errors.  This might be the cause of your problem.  Chrome will break things when validation is incorrect.

Comment: damn, it validates now and i still have the problem. any other ideas? like i said, it worked fine before wordpress entered the picture. that code is available at http://yummrs.com/blog/blog files/

Comment: ok, new piece of info: commenting out `<li id="subscribe_over"><a href="#">subscribe &darr;</a></li>` doesn't fix anything.

Comment: SOLVED. it had to do with some code that changed the position of the background image. chrome doesn't like it when you call hover and hoverIntent on the same element. i combined the hover function with the hoverIntent functions and voila, no more problem. thanks for all your help!! now my html validates, too :)

Answer (score 1):

looks like it's a known bug already for chrome: http://plugins.jquery.com/content/google-chrome-bug-hoverintent

Comment: odd. but why was it working before i put it in wordpress? it never gave me any problems until i brought all the code into wp.

Comment: hmm, did your xhtml declaration change?